# Can one escape a net by Misty Step?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, conditions, teleportation

Lets say a creature is hit by an attack with a net, becoming restrained per the net’s description.

Can the creature free themselves from the net with *misty step*?

Comment: Related: "[Do manacles or ropes teleport with you?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156527)"

Comment: Related on [What items are considered worn or carried?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/what-items-are-considered-worn-or-carried)

Comment: not a duplicate, because the reason you cannot escape a net from Misty Step - is because of the escape rules for a Net, not the rules for Misty Step. And the question accused of duplication does not have Net rules. A Large or smaller creature hit by a net is Restrained until it is freed. Misty Step is not listed as one of the options in the Net rules for freeing someone restrained by the Net; only a strength check and damaging the net.

Comment: @AmethystWizard I’ve voted to leave closed in review. The concerns you raise in your comment apply equally to the net and the iron bands discussed in the dupe target. I think the thing to do here is bounty the target, describing what you would like to see an answer address, or to post an answer there yourself. Alternatively, if the question goes through review without being reopened, you might consider asking a question on [meta] discussing the closure.

Comment: I also made a couple edits, which bumped it to the front page for more attention.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, they cannot.

Misty Step says:

> you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

While this doesnt say anything about clothing and equipment, that is typically assumed, as is logical (who would use this spell otherwise?).

So at least any object on you at the time of casting should not be left behind, which would include a net.

Assuming you apply unofficial [Jeremy Crawford tweets](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/635883187856478208), you could Misty Step out of bonds that are affixed to a surface, but a net is not, so it should still teleport with you.

> **Jeremy Crawford**: It's up to the DM. I'd say you could teleport out of bonds that are fixed to a wall or the like.

Comment: In this case, are you 30 feet away within the net?

Comment: I don't see how a net someone threw at you becomes part of your equipment, rules-wise. Would a stone carefully balanced on the top of your head teleport too? I don't think that there is a clear answer, or at least not as clear as you present it.

Comment: @J.E To be honest, there are not many clear answers in any RPG, as rules and features can never account for every interaction and circumstance. Due to that, we have to try using what I call logical inference; basically, why is something good enough to be used in the first place, and what logical consequences (both positive and negative) result from that.

Comment: I agree that this is a murky area that isn't covered by the rules.  But when an area isn't covered by the rules, we shouldn't be making up rules and handing them out as official -- we should be saying "this isn't covered by the rules, here are some things to think about when making a ruling, ask your DM".

Comment: @J.E In this case, because we can logically infer that anything on your person (clothes, equipment, sweat, etc) teleports as well, then other items that are on you, wanted or unwanted, can as well (at least up to your encumbrance).

Comment: You as a DM could decide to make the inference, but it isn't the only option. See [this question on worn/carried](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/what-items-are-considered-worn-or-carried) for another way to rule this.